# How to cross-compile Clang on Ubuntu for Win32?

Tags: cmake

1. I downloaded & extracted:
   http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/llvm-5.0.1.src.tar.xz
   http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/cfe-5.0.1.src.tar.xz
2. Then:

```
$ mv cfe-5.0.1.src llvm-5.0.1.src/tool/clang
```

3. Created the following `llvm-5.0.1.src/mingw_cross_toolchain.cmake` file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX x86_64-w64-mingw32)

# cross compilers to use for C and C++
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc-posix)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++-posix)
set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gfortran)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-windres)

# target environment on the build host system
#   set 1st to dir with the cross compiler's C/C++ headers/libs
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/lib/gcc/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}/7.3-posix)

# modify default behavior of FIND_XXX() commands to
# search for headers/libs in the target environment and
# search for programs in the build host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

4. Then:

```
$ cd llvm-5.0.1.src
$ mkdir build
# cd build
$ cmake -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../mingw_cross_toolchain.cmake
```

5. Then in the following `build/NATIVE/include/llvm/Config/llvm-config.h` I have:

```
/* Define if this is Unixish platform */
#define LLVM_ON_UNIX 1

/* Define if this is Win32ish platform */
/* #undef LLVM_ON_WIN32 */
```

Which will make the build fail. Since LLVM_ON_WIN32 depends on the WIN32 flag, I tried to define that flag on the command line and in the `mingw_cross_toolchain.cmake` but alas with no effect on the generated `build/NATIVE/include/llvm/Config/llvm-config.h`.

How can we define that WIN32 flag properly?

Comment: How does the build fail? Are there any errors that you can add to your question post?

Comment: Source files make use of LLVM_ON_UNIX and LLVM_ON_WIN32 so if they are not set properly then the build will fail because the internal typedefs are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ok so I need to force by setting the flags in `cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake` to:

```
set(WIN32 1)
set(UNIX 0)
```

2. Then I need to be able to execute the future intermediate Win32 executables:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine-binfmt
$ sudo update-binfmts --import /usr/share/binfmts/wine
```

3. After that I need to set the WINEPATH to find the DLLs:

```
$ export WINEPATH="/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3-posix"
```

Now I'll be able to cross-compile everything properly!